# Gnome shell : why do I need to type TAB or DOWN arrow to loop through open windows in overview

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, user-interface, user-experience

When I press `Super` on Gnome shell, I get the overview of the current workspace with all open windows.

However I can't select any window using the arrow keys unless I press one time on the `DOWN` key or the `TAB` key.

Is this a UI / UX bug ?

I tried on Fedora 31 and Ubuntu 18.04 ; same issue.

Comment: It's because focus is on the search field.
[Detailed description](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177113)